# How to resolve "ERROR: Specified cast is not valid." error during installation?

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

I'm currently receiving this error when installing [Java SE Runtime Environment](https://chocolatey.org/packages/jre8) (`jre8`), updating used to work fine:

```
Searching if new version exists...
ERROR: Specified cast is not valid.
The install of jre8 was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\jre8\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - jre8 (exited -1) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\jre8\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
```

<del>chocolatey.log</del> (I can't paste here because of the 30 000 character length limit, I've deleted the dates)

Comment: The Pastebin log file has been deleted, apparently I somehow set expiration for the paste.

Comment: I don't use Windows anymore, I can't say for certain if this is a Netbeans-related issue. But I certainly had Netbeans installed when asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had this problem.  I did:

```
get-childitem hklm:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall\ |
  foreach { write-host $_.pspath; $_ } | get-itemproperty
```

and it choked on `HKLM:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall\nbi-nb-base-8.2.0.0.201609300101`, which is for Netbeans 8.2.  I see in regedit that NoModify has "(invalid DWORD (32-bit) value)".  `get-itemproperty -erroraction continue` has no effect.

EDIT:  The Netbeans people are finally fixing this currently (not really).  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2523

EDIT:  They will probably never fix it.

Comment: The Regedit path was `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\nbi-tmcbeans-1.0.0.0.0` for me.

Comment: Deleting the `NoModify` value allowed installing [jre8](https://chocolatey.org/packages/jre8) immediately.

Comment: https://newbedev.com/how-to-resolve-error-specified-cast-is-not-valid-error-during-installation

This link is what explained the issue and it was netbeans 8.2. 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2523

Comment: @IT_User Yes I posted that bug, and in Netbeans 12.6 it is STILL not resolved.

Answer (score 5):

This error appears to be the result of `Get-ItemProperty` failing. From your log, the part of the script that is failing is here:

```
  Write-Output "Searching if new version exists..."
  $checkreg64 = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -like '*Java 8*' -and ([Version]$_.DisplayVersion) -eq $version} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  $checkreg32 = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -like '*Java 8*' -and ([Version]$_.DisplayVersion) -eq $version} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

This failure occurs when `Get-ItemProperty` expects to read a registry key of type X and reads a key whose data doesn't match the constraints of the key type. [research1](https://github.com/PSAppDeployToolkit/PSAppDeployToolkit/issues/102) [research2](https://github.com/majkinetor/au-packages/issues/15) [research3](https://github.com/dtgm/chocolatey-packages/issues/92)

The solution [in this case](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/chocolatey/chocolatey_gallery_wkhtmltopdf_099/#comment-2679706558) was to find the invalid key in registry (the registry paths that are queried in `$checkreg64` and `$checkreg32`) and manually recreate it as a DWORD with value 1.

Update:

From the comments, you get "Specified cast is not valid" when querying `Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*`. It is possible there is an unrelated key in this location that contains an invalid subkey, causing the query against this location to fail. We should be able to parse each key individually from the Uninstall location to determine which key we're having trouble querying.

Run the below:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | % { write-host "Key Name:" $_.PSChildName }
```

This should return some results, then, will return the `Specified cast` error. The error will occur on the key harboring the invalid subkey.

For example, if the results of the above look like this:

```
Key Name: fake_key_name_1
Key Name: fake_key_name_2
Key Name: fake_key_name_3
Get-ItemProperty : Specified cast is not valid.
```

Then the last key you were able to successfully query was `fake_key_name_3`. The key we could not query was the next key in the list. Open regedit and browse to the next key name (presumably, `fake_key_name_4`). This is where the failure is. There should be an invalid subkey here. Fix this, then run the command again. If you get no errors, you're all set. If you get more keys with errors, find and fix their invalid subkeys.

In the case of one of the linked examples I originally provided, the user would expect to find a REG_DWORD key with data = "(invalid DWORD (32-bit) value)". This is the key to fix.

Comment: Can you update the answer with full paths? I've navigated to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` in the registry editor, but I don't know how to continue from there.

Comment: For the x64 example: Run `Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -like '*Java 8*' } | select -expandproperty PSChildName`. If the result is {12345}, check for key `HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{12345}\NoModify`.

Comment: I get this error for the command: `Get-ItemProperty : Specified cast is not valid.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Unin ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ItemProperty], InvalidCastException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidCastException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand`

Comment: Great, we've inadvertently confirmed (at least one of) the location(s) of the problem. Manually navigate to HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ through regedit, browsing each subkey for the one containing the DisplayName like "Java 8". That's where NoModify will be. Let me know if you'd like to move this discussion to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access).

Comment: The issue is that I can't effective search registry — but that's another question. I've searched for "java" in Regedit, but only entries in Notepad++ folder are found.

Comment: The maintainer's Chocolatey package Github page: https://github.com/proudcanadianeh/ChocoPackages/issues/18

Comment: I've updated my answer to include more troubleshooting steps.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Sorry, I put the topic on hold for a while as the process is getting demanding for my skill level — I'll try to finish early next week. Thank you for the concern.

Comment: This didn't work well for me.  I had to skip 3 keys down from MozillaMaintenanceService to nbi-nb-base-8.2.0.0.201609300101 to find the offending NoModify value from Netbeans.

Comment: @js2010: Stopped at Mozilla Maintenance Service for me as well.

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the right direction with your answer, the question has now been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a specific answer for the NetBeans cause of this issue in PowerShell, no manual registry traversing needed.

```
## Check for and fix known exception where broken registry entry breaks Uninstall querying
# https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2523
try {
    Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*,HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* -ea 0 | Out-Null
} catch [System.InvalidCastException] {
    $NetBeans = (& reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" | ?{$_ -match 'nbi\-'})
    $NetBeans | %{ If (Get-Item ($_ -Replace 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE','HKLM:') -ea 0).Property -contains 'NoModify') { & reg add $_ /v NoModify /t REG_DWORD /d 0x1 /f | Out-Null } }
}
```